# How to create a second order linear model in MATLAB if I have 5 predictors.?

Tags: matlab, data-analysis

Basically, I have a dataset with 5 predictors and one target variable. I need to fit a second order linear model in MATLAB. So do I need to create a total of 20 predictor variables and then use  fitlm or is there any other approach so that I donot need to create 20 variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html#inputarg_modelspec) you can fit a second order model using `fitlm` by specifying the modelspec argument as `'quadratic'`. Here's an example with simulated data.

```
% generate some random correlated data
mu = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
sigma = [1.6737    1.0183    1.0279   -1.8104   -2.4717   -2.2875; ...
         1.0183    2.9619   -0.2512   -1.9997    2.4059   -1.7610; ...
         1.0279   -0.2512    2.7031   -0.2611   -3.9707   -0.6580; ...
        -1.8104   -1.9997   -0.2611    5.8947   -2.9645    4.1843; ...
        -2.4717    2.4059   -3.9707   -2.9645   15.3447    1.6498; ...
        -2.2875   -1.7610   -0.6580    4.1843    1.6498    6.0116];
data_train = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,10000);
data_test = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,1000);

% fit second order polynomial
predictors_train = data_train(:,1:5);
target_train = data_train(:,6);
model = fitlm(predictors_train, target_train, 'quadratic');

% test using data from same distribution
predictors_test = data_test(:,1:5);
target_test = data_test(:,6);
target_est = predict(model, predictors_test);

% report root mean-square error
rmse = sqrt(mean((target_est - target_test).^2))
```